# Android - Google BillingClient queryPurchaseHistoryAsync response

Tags: android

the doc for queryPurchaseHistoryAsync simply states:

> Returns the most recent purchase made by the user for each SKU, even
> if that purchase is expired, canceled, or consumed.

Can someone confirm that it ONLY returns purchases for this app?  We want to be able to check past subscriptions of this app but are weary of the privacy issues related to getting ALL past purchases

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The BillingClient is related to your package name only. Absolutely you need to see all the transactions and purchases of your only app related to this package (xxx.yyyy.zzzz)

Comment: @shogunnassar post this as an answer so I can give you the bounty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BillingClient is related to your package name only. Absolutely you need to see all the transactions and purchases of your only app related to this package (xxx.yyyy.zzzz)

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is ONLY from your app, I am 100% sure, it goes without saying, it returns purchases details for items bought within your app only.